# JIRA plugin on jenkins not set the JIRA_ISSUES variable

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jira

I have jenkins job for with `GitHub Pull Request Builder`.

In build, I added first step to set the `JIRA_ISSUE` variable.

**JIRA: Add related environment variables to build**

```
Extracts JIRA information for the build to environment variables.
Available variables:
JIRA_ISSUES - A comma separated list of issues which are referenced in the version control system changelog
JIRA_URL - Primary URL for the JIRA server
Typical usage:

Add this build step
Use the "Progress JIRA issues by workflow action" or "Move issues matching JQL to the specified version" with JQL like:
issue in (${JIRA_ISSUES})
```

Second step is to update these jira issues.

```
<builders>
    <hudson.plugins.jira.JiraEnvironmentVariableBuilder plugin="jira@3.0.0"/>
    <hudson.plugins.jira.JiraIssueUpdateBuilder plugin="jira@3.0.0">
      <jqlSearch>issue in (${JIRA_ISSUES})</jqlSearch>
      <workflowActionName>Ready for Review</workflowActionName>
      <comment>add comment</comment>
    </hudson.plugins.jira.JiraIssueUpdateBuilder>
</builders>
```

When I create PR, and it trigger the job, it not set `JIRA_ISSUES`

```
GitHub pull request #356 of commit 2e2b92d107a5460c4cc593fcab78c63f800d6472, no merge conflicts.
Setting status of 2e2b92d107a5460c4cc593fcab78c63f800d6472 to PENDING with url https://myjenkins.com/job/cicd-myjob-prtest-unittest/69/ and message: 'running tox...'
Using context: tox testing
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building remotely on myslave.node.box.com (linux) in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/cicd-myjob-prtest-unittest
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://mygithub.com/myuser/myproject.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://mygithub.com/myuser/myproject.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials Github Service Account Username with token
 > git fetch --tags --progress https://mygithub.com/myuser/myproject.git +refs/pull/*:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/pr/356/merge^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/pr/356/merge^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 0ff9e43bbc1385303429f7bcf93fea36e8c455d3 (refs/remotes/origin/pr/356/merge)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 0ff9e43bbc1385303429f7bcf93fea36e8c455d3
Commit message: "Merge 2e2b92d107a5460c4cc593fcab78c63f800d6472 into 731994024e723b1257374f521b4784060df9e5b5"
First time build. Skipping changelog.
[JIRA] Setting JIRA_ISSUES to .
[JIRA] Updating issues using workflow action Ready for Review.
[JIRA] JQL: issue in ()
[JIRA] Updating issue MYPROJECT-1234
Setting status of 2e2b92d107a5460c4cc593fcab78c63f800d6472 to SUCCESS with url https://myjenkins.com/job/cicd-myjob-prtest-unittest/69/ and message: 'All is well.
 '
Using context: tox testing
Finished: SUCCESS
```

The `[JIRA] Updating issue MYPROJECT-1234` is from `publisher`

```
<publishers>
    <hudson.plugins.jira.JiraIssueUpdater plugin="jira@3.0.0">
      <issueSelector class="hudson.plugins.jira.selector.JqlIssueSelector">
        <jql>issue=MYPROJECT-1234</jql>
      </issueSelector>
      <labels/>
    </hudson.plugins.jira.JiraIssueUpdater>
</publishers>
```

If I look for change log for commit `2e2b92d107a5460c4cc593fcab78c63f800d6472` it has the jira issue in comment and title.

```
commit 2e2b92d107a5460c4cc593fcab78c63f800d6472 (HEAD -> MYPROJECT-1234, origin/MYPROJECT-1234)
Author: myuser <myuser@mygithub.com>
Date:   Tue Aug 21 15:55:41 2018 -0500

    MYPROJECT-1234: Tox testing

    MYPROJECT-1234 change the data.
```

Why is the `JiraEnvironmentVariableBuilder` not able to set `JIRA_ISSUES` to `MYPROJECT-1234` while it is present in the changelog?

Comment: Could you indicate whether you solved the issue?

Comment: No, I moved my job to pipeline, and now I am running loop over all the issues. If you get solution, please update this.